# HHVM handles large integers differently - what's the solution

Tags: hhvm

I am experimenting with HHVM and tried a factorial! implementation. What I noticed was that whereas PHP will help me out and convert large integers into scientific notation, HHVM won't do this.
How do I handle large integers in HHVM?

```
<?php //factorial.php
$n = $argv[1];
$factorial = array_product(range(1, $n));
echo $factorial . "\n";     //direct output
printf("%g\n", $factorial); //force scientific notation

#> php factorial.php 52 //how many ways can you shuffle a deck of cards (php)?
   8.0658175170944E+67
   8.06582e+67

#> hhvm factorial.php 52 //how many ways can you shuffle a deck of cards (hhvm)?
   -8452693550620999680
   -8.45269e+18
```

So PHP is much more lenient about the maximum size of an integer, what do I need to do to get the correct result through hhvm?

Comment: I'm pretty sure what's happening is that PHP is converting the integer into a floating point number (much larger range but at cost of precision), since [`array_product` is documented as able to return either](http://uk3.php.net/array_product). It may technically be a bug that HHVM doesn't do the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in HHVM. We have an ini setting `hhvm.hack.lang.ints_overflow_to_ints` which defaults to false, but it looks like we're ignoring it for `array_product`. Can you file an issue on our github please?